# SQL Server 2008 - Create a Join Table

Tags: sql-server, join, create-table

I'm having issues creating a simple join table (associative table, etc. whatever your flavor is).

These are test tables, so there is not much to them.

First table is

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CareerField(
CareerFieldID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CareerFieldName varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Second Table is

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Cluster(
ClusterID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
ClusterName varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Third table (join table) to create a many-to-many relationship is

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CareerField_Cluster(
CareerFieldID int NOT NULL,
ClusterID int NOT NULL
)
```

I am trying to set foreign keys in this third table using the following

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CareerField_Cluster
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CareerField_Cluster_CareerFieldID
FOREIGN KEY(CareerFieldID) REFERENCES dbo.CareerField(CareerFieldID)

ALTER TABLE dbo.CareerField_Cluster
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CareerField_Cluster_ClusterID
FOREIGN KEY(ClusterID) REFERENCES dbo.Cluster(ClusterID)
```

However, I keep getting an error of

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.CareerField' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_CareerField_Cluster_CareerFieldID'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I try setting both fields as a primary key, but it will not allow me to select a separate table when creating the key - I can't select CareerFieldID to reference CareerField Table and then ClusterID to reference Cluster Table.

I've not had this issue with MySQL and I am new to SQL Server. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to designate Primary Keys for the referenced tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of your tables `CareerField` and `Cluster`, ensure you have a PK designated via the `CONSTRAINT` directive.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CareerField]
(
    [CareerFieldID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CareerFieldName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Career] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CareerFieldID] ASC
    )
)
```

Comment: After I beat my head against my desk, I will curse my name for hours. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks! :)